# Django - Meta.base_manager_name - make related argument in the custom queryset and manager

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-oscar, django-managers

I have a custom model manager and a custom queryset defined specifically for related obj which means I have defined Meta.base_manager_name in the model.

I would like to use a all() manager method which fetches related obj on a OneToOneFeild.

Now I know this does not make sense since OneToOneFeild will always return one obj there is no need for a all() method.  I am working on django-oscar project and am extending its "Partner" model. It originally has a field "users" with  ManyToManyField and now changed to a OneToOneFeild.

The users field is called in code several times using relation user.partners.all(). I don't want to extend/modify all these places (am I being lazy here?) since I want to keep the code as upgrade friendly as possible and so instead I wanted to have all() model manager defined which will work. Not sure if it is a good idea?

the all() method takes user arg to return queryset of the user instance

```
class PartnerQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def all(self, user):
        return self.filter(user=user)

class PartnerManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return PartnerQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def all(self, user):
        return self.get_queryset().all(users)

class Partner(models.Model):
    objects = PartnerManager()

    class Meta:
        base_manager_name = 'objects'
```

The problem is when it is used with related obj it asks for user arg which makes sense but since I am using it with a related obj I wanted to use the related obj as arg so,

```
user.partner.all() - should use user as arg and fetch the results 

user.partner.all(user) - and I should not have to do the below
```

2 related questions:
1) Does this make sense - should I be doing this?
2) how I can achieve user.partner.all() without adding user in arg

PS: I know i can work with middleware to get_current_user but this function is not reliable as per some of the responses on a different question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you are trying to do will work. Your new situation with a OneToOneField gives you the partner instance.

```
>>>> user.partner
<Partner xxx>
```

While in the old situation with the ManyToManyField, the `PartnerQuerySet` would've been returned.

```
>>>> user.partner
<PartnerQuerySet []>
```

A solution would be to create a custom [OneToOneField](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L961), but this would most probably violate the "simple is better than complex" rule and in the end may even be more work than changing all existing `.all()`'s.